# Using C# htmlagilitypack for a shorter preview version of text with html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

The thing I want to accomplish with htmlagilitypack is to make a shorter version of a content while keeping its html. Sort of for preview usage.

For example, lets say I have `"1234567890<div></div>1234567890"` but the length is set to max 11. This should give a result of `1234567890<div></div>1`.

Im not sure right now how to get there, as the still valid html should be kept and sort of ignored for being included when checking for a max length of a text with html content. RegEx is not a valid solution for this. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method which returns a new `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`:

```
public static HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetPreview(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument orginal, int maxTextLength)
{
    var docPreview = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    docPreview.DocumentNode.CopyFrom(orginal.DocumentNode, false); // documentation bug in HtmlAgilityPack, false means deep-copy

    string allText = docPreview.DocumentNode.InnerText;
    int remainingDelete = allText.Length - maxTextLength;

    if (remainingDelete <= 0)
        return docPreview;  // you are finished

    // select only text nodes
    HtmlNodeCollection allTextNodes = docPreview.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']");
    // iterate text nodes backwards
    for (int i = allTextNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        HtmlTextNode textNode = allTextNodes[i] as HtmlTextNode;
        if (textNode == null) continue;

        int length = remainingDelete >= textNode.Text.Length ? 0 : textNode.Text.Length - remainingDelete;
        int removeLetterCount = textNode.Text.Length - length;
        remainingDelete = remainingDelete - removeLetterCount;

        textNode.Text = textNode.Text.Substring(0, length);

        if (remainingDelete == 0)
            break;
    }

    return docPreview;
}
```

Your sample:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("1234567890<div></div>1234567890");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docPreview = GetPreview(doc, 11);
Console.WriteLine(docPreview.DocumentNode.InnerHtml); // 1234567890<div></div>1
```